How do i close a popup in selenium python
I'm currently working on a project using selenium, chrome driver, and I've encountered an issue where i am unable to close a popup which asks "... wants to open this application."
I have already had this problem with the camera and microphone permissions.
However, I fixed that by passing in driver options, but I'm unable to find any options to fix this.
Basically, is there an option I can pass in to automatically decline any website asking me to open other apps, or is there something else I can do to fix this?
